# Batch file for 'mclip.py' from "Automate the boring stuff with python" chapter 6 not working as intended

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing the code for Project: Multi-Clipboard Automatic Messages (in Mu). The code is written in the book, and it works from cmd through "python mclip.py 'keyphrase'". However, I am not able to run the code from a batch file as I am stuck at len(sys.argv) < 2 then sys.exit() (code attached)

The only way I could run it from the batch file was by using sys.argv.append(input()) and I need to know if I can do this (I hear it is a bad practice) or if there is a better solution.

batch file info:
@py.exe C:\Users\kamal\pythonScripts\mclip.py %*
@pause

```
#! python3
# mclip.py - A multi-clipboard program.

TEXT = {'Agree': """Yes, I agree. That sounds fine to me.""",
'Busy': """Sorry, can we do this later this week or next week?""",
'upsell': """Would you consider making this a monthly donation?"""}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text')
    sys.exit()
    
keyphrase = sys.argv[1]     #first cmmand line arg is the keyphrase

if keyphrase in TEXT:
    pyperclip.copy(TEXT[keyphrase])
    print('Text for ' + keyphrase + ' copied to clipboard')
else:
    print('There is no text for ' + keyphrase)
```